# Meaning and significance testing of coefficients in lasso/ridge regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, lasso, ridge-regression

Can somebody explain the importance of significance testing in ridge/lasso regression? Is it necessary to do it?

And, how can we interpret the coefficients of ridge regression which are penalized?

Comment: Necessary for what?

Comment: @Dawny33: Why did you think that [ridge-regression] and [statistical-significance] are "extra tags" in a question asking about ridge regression and significance testing? I have added them back.